# How to feed decimal_y_values for training where last layer of model has 10 neurons with softmax activation and loss is Earth Mover Loss

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, keras, pytorch

What should be the format/data types of y-labels for training if the actual y-labels cab be any decimal number between 0-9 (4.1,8.5  etc) and the last output layer is defined as:

```
out = Dense(10,activation='softmax')(previous_layer)
```

and the loss fuction to use is:

```
def earth_mover_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    cdf_ytrue = K.cumsum(y_true, axis=-1)
    cdf_ypred = K.cumsum(y_pred, axis=-1)
    samplewise_emd = K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(K.abs(cdf_ytrue - cdf_ypred)), axis=-1))
    return K.mean(samplewise_emd)
```

How should I feed the labels in my network. I want to mimic [this model](https://github.com/titu1994/neural-image-assessment/blob/master/train_inception_resnet.py)

Comment: you can use `10 * sigmoid`. `sigmoid` has range from `0-1` and multiplying it by `10` gets you `0-10`

Comment: How do I feed Y-values in the model?? Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: i am confused now, what are you asking? from your poorly worded question all I infer is what should be the activation of the last layer if I need the network to output decimals from 0 to 10

Comment: I am asking that How is it possible to train a model using given Earth Moving loss,last output layer  with sigmoid activation and the y_labels as decimal numbers?

Comment: sigmoid or softmax? and why is anything given? if you want to train you should be able to tweak parameters

Comment: I want to replicate NIMA Research Paper by Google  [implemented in this Code](https://github.com/titu1994/neural-image-assessment/blob/master/train_inception_resnet.py)